# Opening .doc files from External Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I saw an article in a blog about opening .doc files from External Tools in Visual Studio 2008 (C# language spec in this case).

I can't find this article anymore. Does anyone know how to do this (and also for .pdfs)? There doesn't seem to be much guidance on doing this in VS.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do. Go to "Tools `->` External tools...." Set the command to the path of MSWord (or PDF reader of your choice) and set arguments to the path of the document.

For example, in my PC:

- Title: C# Language Specification
- Command: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE`
- Arguments: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.doc"`

Make sure you put the argument path in quotes if it contains characters like space, as it needs to be treated as a single argument to the command.

Comment: Btw, does the file have to be in the program directory (Visual Studio)? It doesn't work otherwise, but I thought it wouldn't matter.

Comment: No it doesn't matter. Make sure you put the argument path in double quotes.